# Uniqueness of derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

There is one confusing moment. How did Rudin get (16)? My though is the following:
Since $\dfrac{|B\mathbf{h}|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ as $\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}$. Fixing $\mathbf{h}\neq\mathbf{0}$ if $t\to 0$ then $t\mathbf{h}\to 0$. Hence $\dfrac{|B(t\mathbf{h})|}{|t\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ by above.

Am I right? Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Prayed to the math gods :P

Comment: @ZelosMalum, sorry?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This essentially amounts to composition of limits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that the derivative is unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611254/proof-that-the-derivative-is-unique)